# Lua table overridden

Tags: lua

This is supposed to be a simple backtracking function. The dest is a global table that is being properly edited in the function. The prev table is supposed to keep track of my previous positions as to not revisit them. However, my prev table always turns out empty. I'm a novice. If there is any other helpful information I will be happy to provide it. u

```
function GoTo(dest, prev)
    -- base case
    if dest[1] == position[1] and dest[2] == position[2] and dest[3] == position[3] then
        return true
    end
    local prev = prev or {}
    -- save destination as to not return here
    prev[table.concat(position)] = true
    -- create key for next move
    local key = {0,0,0}
    for i,v in ipairs(dest) do
        if dest[i] ~= 0 then
            key[i] = dest[i]/math.abs(dest[i])
        end
    end
    -- attempt to move in optimal direction
    for i,v in ipairs(key) do
        if key[i] ~= 0 then
            -- check if next move leads to a visited destination
            position[i] = position[i] + v
            local check = prev[table.concat(position)]
            position[i] = position[i] - v
            if not check then
                if moveTo(i,v) then
                    if GoTo(dest, prev) then
                        return true
                    end
                    -- go back
                    if not moveTo(i, -v) then
                        error("cannot backtrack")
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> local prev = prev or {}

You create a local variable in your function and initialize it from a parameter with the same name that is being passed in, which hides all the changes inside the function and that's likely why you don't see any changes for that table. You need to initialize that table outside the function and pass its value in (and remove that `local prev` statement).

Comment: I removed ```local prev```. I tried calling the function like ```GoTo(dest, {})```. I tried initializing the table to pass as local and global. I also created a wrapper ```function goTo(dest) local record = {} return GoTo(dest, record) end```. I tried this making record local and leaving it global. I still can't confirm that the table is changing. The way I am checking the contents of the table is ```for i,v in ipairs(prev) do print(i,v) end``` in the GoTo function right after I edit the table. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @spanish_gunther you can't check `prev` with `ipairs` need to use `pairs`. `ipairs` will look for sequential keys starting from `1` your `prev` table is not organized in a way for `ipairs` to work.

Comment: @Nifim of course! It is working as expected. Thank you both very much.

Comment: You may want to accept the answer if it worked for you.